# Promise.all fails if more than 1000 https requests

Tags: node.js, promise

I am trying to measure performace of my node app which basically performes numbers of GET requeasts.

To evaluate performance I decided to use data set of size 1 milllion. But it fails after 1000 requests.

My code looks something like this:

```
let promiseArray = [] 
for(let i = 0; i < 10001; i++) {
  promiseArray.push(
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      https.get("https://google.com", (response, err) => {
        if (err) reject(err);
        let bodyChunks = [];
        response
          .on("data", chunks => {
            bodyChunks.push(chunks);
          })
          .on("end", () => {
            var body = Buffer.concat(bodyChunks);
            resolve(body);
          });
      });
    })
  );
}

fetchData = async () => {
  result = await Promise.all(promiseArray);
  console.log(result);
}

fetchData();
```

It works fine till 1000 requests but as soon as I do 1001, it gives following error:

> Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND google.com google.com:443

I also tried using bluebird's `Promise.map`:

```
var foo = Array(10000)
  .fill()
  .map((v, i) => i);

Promise.map(
  foo,
  function(i) {
    // Promise.map awaits for returned promises as well.
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      https.get("https://google.com", (response, err) => {
        if (err) reject(err);
        let bodyChunks = [];
        response
          .on("data", chunks => {
            bodyChunks.push(chunks);
          })
          .on("end", () => {
            var body = Buffer.concat(bodyChunks);
            resolve(body);
          });
      });
    });
  },
  { concurrency: 100 }
).then(function() {
  console.log("done");
});
```

It gave me error:

> Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.217.194.113:443

This does not even work for 10 requests!

Can anyone help me figure out how to make more than 1000 request using Promise.all()?

Comment: It's not a `Promise.all` problem. it's a network issue, you're doing more requests than the amount your network can handle, and then it's failing to resolve.

Comment: You will need to send it in batches, the limit of each batch will depend on the OS, hardware, network and a lot of things. If you try that on a Network optimized VM on EC2, you will be able to process more requests than trying that in your local computer.